# My JQuery-AJAX code in my Django project for displaying a default value in a calculation based field fails to do so?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

These are two of few models in my project:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=models.ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date_of_admission=models.DateField(default=None)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    package_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Receivables(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    rt_number=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    approved_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    approval_date=models.DateField(default=None)
    proposed_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    done_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    base_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    expected_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    receivables_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I needed the `approved_package` in `Receivables` to display a `default` value calculated by subtracting `discount` from the `total_package` in `Package`. And it should all be in real time. So I wrote an `AJAX` code in `Jquery` in an `HTML` file and `included` the file in my main `template`. The code looks like:

```
<script>
    $('select').change(function () {
     var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
     var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
     var textSelected   = optionSelected.text();
     var csr = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
     console.log(textSelected);
        pkg={patient:textSelected, csrfmiddlewaretoken:csr}
        $.ajax({
            url:"{% url 'pt_name' %}",
            method: "POST",
            data: pkg,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.pkg);
                console.log(data.ptt);
                var tp=data.pkg;
                var ptt=data.ptt;
                $('#id_discount').change(function(){
                    console.log('tp value: ', tp);
                    console.log('ptt value: ', ptt);
                    var discount=document.getElementById('id_discount').value;
                    console.log('discount value: ', discount);
                    var approved_package=document.getElementById('id_approved_package').value;
                    if (ptt=='CASH')
                    approved_package=tp-discount;
                    console.log('approved package new value: ', approved_package);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code runs fine in the `console` of the browser. It fires all the codes. It calculates the `approved_package` but the result still does not show up in the field as a default value when I enter the `discount` value. What is wrong with my code? Can someone point it out?

**GOT IT**

It should have been like this:

```
var approved_package=document.getElementById('id_approved_package');
if (ptt=='CASH')
    approved_package.value=tp-discount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to change Html element value after calculating the new approved_package value.

```
    var approved_package=document.getElementById('id_approved_package').value;
    if (ptt=='CASH')
        approved_package.value=tp-discount;

    console.log('approved package new value: ', approved_package);
```

Comment: It shows following error:
(index):81 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value is not a function

Comment: If I am not wrong val() is a function and value is not. It is just an attribute.

Comment: can you share your HTML file

Comment: Corrected it. I have updated my post. Towards the end, I have added the corrected code. Thanks by the way. :)